# what does the tag <# or <#= do? i just noticed it inside a wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

here is a sample of what i saw, i figured php.ini had something like that but i wasnt able to find anything in php.ini. Then i tried looking in google to see if it has to do with javascript but no results exist for <# or <#= .

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-nf-wh-args">
            <#
            if ( 'new' == object_id ) {
                var x = jQuery( '.new-wh-args' ).length;
                var key_name = 'wh_args[new][' + x + '][key]';
                var field_name = 'wh_args[new][' + x + '][field]';
                var class_name = 'new-wh-args';
            } else {
                var key_name = 'wh_args[' + object_id + '][key]';
                var field_name = 'wh_args[' + object_id + '][field]';
                var class_name = '';
            }
            #>
            <div class="single-wh-args nf-wh-args">
                <span style="float:left">
                <a href="#" class="nf-wh-args-delete remove" style=""><div class="dashicons dashicons-dismiss"></div></a>
                <?php _e( 'Key', 'ninja-forms-wh' ); ?> <input type="text" name="<#= key_name #>" value="<#= args.key #>" placeholder="Key" class="nf-wh-args-key <#= class_name #>">
                </span>
                <input name="<#= field_name #>" type="text" id="" value="<#= args.field #>" class="nf-tokenize" placeholder="Field" data-key="wh_args_<#=object_id #>" data-type="all" />
            </div>
        </script>
```

Comment: It depends on what template language that is embedded in that script element.

Comment: its called webhooks for ninja forms, a premium plugin.

Comment: looks like a js template framework e.g. underscore uses `<%` as a identifer, or it could for php to pick out fields in the html document.